# Passing the context of one RNN to another

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have 'n' number of RNNs and I wish to pass the context of first RNN along with second input to second RNN, then the context of this(second)RNN and third input to third RNN and so on. How can I achieve this in Keras. I wish to use `keras.layers.SimpleRNN`. Is there a way to fetch the context of previous layer? If not keras what can I use to achieve the same?

Comment: I think by "context" you mean hidden state of the RNN layer, right?

Comment: @today Yes, the context is same as hidden state of previous RNN

Comment: And what do you mean by "first input", "second input", etc.? Are you referring to timesteps? Or each one of them is a timeseries? It would be great if you explain clearly what is the input of the whole model.

Comment: @today I am trying to implement a many to one RNN where each RNN has one input(which signifies one time instance) and I have 'n' such time instances, therefore 'n' such RNNs. Now I wish to take hidden state vector of previous RNN and the input(time slice for this RNN) and get its hidden state vector until I reach the last RNN.

Comment: You mean one single timestep? If that's the case then what's the use of using a RNN to process one single timestep?